# How to send image byte array in JSON POST in Java

Tags: java, image, byte, arrays

I am sending an image file along with other form elements in my java application.
Before sending my content to API, in JS ajax call, I am using

```
if (content != "") {
    sendData = JSON.parse(content);
   }
```

since the byte array contains \, "" and other characters, JSON parsing fails here. Is there any way to encode the byte array and decode it in service layer? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your condition `content != ""` will *always* be true (even if `content` is `null` or an empty string), unless you have explicitly assigned `content = ""`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : Yes, my condition will always be true. If it is false, I am breaking this flow and processing something else.

Comment: You want your condition to be `false` for empty strings, don't you? Well, it is not what you are getting...

Comment: I want the bytestream to be encoded by some means in java before the ajax POST request so that byte stream will be passed inside my json object. And the same will be decoded in my API.

Comment: Can I use base64 encoding? or is there any other way?

Comment: @TobiasRoland `"" == ""` can never be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the bitmap (or any binary data) to text using base64 (which makes it a String) I wouldn't use one of the Base64 classes in the JVM unless you are fully aware that they are for internal use. (may not be available on all JDKs and could change in future versions)

You could copy java.util.prefs.Base64 if you don't have one in a library already.

Comment: There is a *public* Base64 codec in JAXB, which is included with the JDK.

Comment: @Developer SuRu - Im using jdk 1.6. I think this package is not supported. Can you please suggest the right one for 1.6?

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4808229 
see this bug report and use jdk1.7 or copy that file from jdk1.7 src to your project.

Comment: You can also use the Base64 provided by Apache Commons Codec, see this link with an example: http://myjeeva.com/how-to-convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java.html